# Create menu login but i can get in with empty password in Android Java

Tags: java, android, authentication, login-control

There is a problem with my java code, when I emptied my username and password and click login, I can still get into the main menu, if there are less with my code? where do I need to fix it? please help

### LoginActivity.Java

```
// Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then there might be something wrong with your UserFunction class or with your server backend service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write your PHP code. I think that you missed a condition !!!
Also, you can add a condition in your LoginActivity like that:

```
if((inputEmail.getText().toString()).isEmpty() ||  
   (inputPassword.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
{
   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please fill out Username and Password !!!",
   5000).show();
}
else
{
   //check for login response
}
```

Comment: If you are using ANDROIDHIVE.COM tutorial, mentioned that it works fine without using this code. You must check your codes (PHP or UserFunction) to find out your solution. If you use my solution and using ANDROIDHIVE.COM tutorial, you are checking blank email and password fields twice in your project. I suggest you to use one of them.